# Is EODDATA.com down? Are they still in business?

Tags: market-data, historical, trends

Does anyone have information on eoddata.com? I have been trying to access data for several days without success. I usually receive a download every evening. I have sent multiple support messages with no rely. I keep getting error message that the site is not available.
Thanks.
John